# Mockdata Cosmosdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I waned to load some test data into Cosmos db and not able to do it in bulk. So, how can we load  sample test data in bulk into cosmos tables which is similar to
data loader utility to bring the mock data into cosmos tables?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. What issues are you having, loading data? Also, you tagged your question as `[azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi]` and `[azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi]` - these APIs are not the same as the Table API. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: have removed those and my intention is to create some sample tables and load some test data into it from excel.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Azure Cosmos DB: Data migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

The Microsoft docs says:
"You can import from JSON files, CSV files, SQL, MongoDB, Azure Table storage, Amazon DynamoDB, and even Azure Cosmos DB SQL API collections, and you migrate that data to collections and tables for use with Azure Cosmos DB."